# Internal error when merging tags

Tags: bug, tags, moderator-tools

I tried to merge the tag [check-my-answer](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/check-my-answer) into [check-my-proof](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/check-my-proof), because insofar as these tags mean anything (which is [not really the case](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/761/lets-eliminate-tagcheck-my-proof)), it's the same thing: “I've solved a problem, here's how, is this right?” — and this is science, so the how always involves a proof.

After clicking the “Perform Merge” button on the [merge confirmation screen](https://cs.stackexchange.com/admin/merge-tags?preview=true&mastertag=check-my-proof%20&removetag=check-my-answer&ensuresynonym=True),
I was redirected to an [Oops page](https://cs.stackexchange.com/error?aspxerrorpath=/admin/merge-tags): “Oops! Something Bad Happened!”.

Comment: A fellow moderator reported having the same problem when a synonym suggestion existed in the other direction, and indeed [tag:check-my-answer] has been suggested as a synonym of [tag:check-my-proof]. So this is [this bug](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/175176/tag-merging-with-synonym-mapping-foo-bar-fails-if-proposal-for-bar-fo) then.